# How to open a webpage in the same tab upon clicking a link in the mail

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, anchor

I want to open a webpage in the same tab by clicking a link from email. 
So, If the webpage is already open in a tab, By clicking the link in email should not open another tab but should use the same tab to render the webpage.

For example  - if **https://example.com/index.html** is already open in a tab, By clicking **https://example.com/index.html** link from email should not open another tab but should open the application in the same tab.

I understand, we can do this programatically using Javascript like `window.open("https://example.com/index.html","_self")` but is there a way to form the URL to be used in email to open the webpage to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: There is no way you can do that - and if you could do that, browser manufactorers would shut it down. Do not mess with the behaviour of the user. If the user wants to have your link in an already opened tab, he would open it there.

Comment: absolutelly, there´s no way,

Comment: Got it.  Had the same thoughts. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use target="_self" in a page

```
<a href="https://example.com/index.html" target="_self">The Link</a>
```

From an email... not possible, because the email client has no idea in what tab the standard browser is

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not technically possible. There are no ways to send this type of instructions from an email client to the browser.
Moreover, javascript is not allowed in emails.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for links in e-mails. Usually, the mail service provider is set to open it in a new tab so that the user is still connected.